# visual studio Word Addin taking more than 15 seconds to close word

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsto, office-addins

I have developed Word addin using visual studio 2012. .net framework is 4.5. It is working fine. Only problem is when user closes the word file it takes around 15 seconds for word to close down after we click on “x”.

It closes immediately on my machine. My machines configuration is given below:
- .Net framework 4.5.2.
- VSTo 10.0.50903 and 
- operating system is windows 7 64 bit.

While it takes time on clients machine to close (15 seconds or more). Client has following configuration.
-  Visual Studio 2010 tools for office runtime  x64 version is  10.0.50325.00
-  Operating system of Citrix Server where they access word. Windows server 2008 R2 enterprise SP1 64 bit
- .Net Framework version? 4.5.2

They don't have any other addin installed.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code that you use to open and close the document?

Comment: User closes the Word by clicking close button (X sign) on word file. My addin just creates some record in CRM. It takes time to close even if user doesnt click on my addin button and closes word directly.

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I ran into the same issue with my project ...

Answer (score 0):

try intercepting OnFormClosing event and do the following

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   yourWordObject.Quit();
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(yourWordObject);
   base.OnFormClosing(e);

}
```

Comment: why do we need this? why it is happening on clients environment only? It doesn't take time on my machine. i have checked on many machines but happening on clients machine only. where this code will be added? in this.Addin.cs class?

Comment: are you able to intercept the closing window event? Maybe the code that I've written can help you to free the memory from your word object

Comment: I have added button on ribbontoolbar. Onclick of button i am calling methods of ThisAddIn.cs. ThisAddIn.cs has two events ThisAddIn_Startup and ThisAddIn_Shutdown. Should i write code  yourWordObject.Quit();
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(yourWordObject) on shutdown event? I am not showing any window or form on click of button.

Comment: Ok.. I will try. But this issue happens even if user doesn't click on Addin button. If we disable our Adddin word closes smoothly.

Comment: It didn't help. Do i need to cal gc.collect as well?

Comment: I think that in your case it could be a solution to call `GC.Collect`. try and let me know

Comment: I have created addin from scratch. This addin was not having any code. Just one alert. It is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the normal.dot file (don't forget to copy it somewhere to recover if required)?

Did you try to create a log file to see what happens on the problematic PC?

Also make sure that you release all underlying COM objects in the code instantly. Use *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject* to release a Word object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28office.12%29.aspx) article. It is related to Outlook, but the same principles can be applied to all Office applications.

Comment: No, I didnt try to remove Normal.dotm. It works fine even if Normal.dotm file is there. Problem is with Word addin that i have created. When we disable Word addin it closes fine.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in project?

Comment: Yes. I have tried with Empty project as well and issue is still there.

Comment: Did you add any code to the sample add-in? Do you have any other add-ins installed for Word?

Comment: I have just added some alert message. No, When they disable my addin it works fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Where did you add an alert message?

Comment: I have added ribbon tool bar. On ribbon tool bar i have added button. on click of button i am showing message.                                 MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked!");

Comment: Did you try to install the same version of VSTO runtime on the problematic PC? Does it help?

Comment: i didn't try. Do you think any other issue apart from this?

Comment: Nope. Try to install the same version of VSTO runtime first.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with using an ElementHost. Supposedly it was fixed in an April 10, 2014 release of the VSTO 2010 runtime. See [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783019/word-slow-shutdown-on-windows-8-when-using-wpf-in-application-addin) (the title says Windows 8 but I don't think that part is pertinent).